# "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: =; Is a directory"getting error running model_main.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I ran the command:

```
python3 research/object_detection/legacy/train.py \
    --logtostderr \
    --train_dir = training/ \
    --pipeline_config_path = training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

but I am getting this error:

```
WARNING: The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py:125: main (from __main__) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use object_detection/model_main.py.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "research/object_detection/legacy/train.py", line 184, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "research/object_detection/legacy/train.py", line 93, in main
    FLAGS.pipeline_config_path)
  File "/home/apoorva/Tensorflowapi/models-master/research/slim/object_detection/utils/config_util.py", line 97, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    proto_str = f.read()
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 132, in read
    pywrap_tensorflow.ReadFromStream(self._read_buf, length, status))
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: =; Is a directory
```

I ran `train.py` in `models/research/object_detection/legacy`, got the same error so tried to run `model_main.py` which is the later version of `train.py` but still unable to solve the problem.

```
python3 research/object_detection/legacy/train.py \
    --logtostderr \
    --train_dir = training/ \
    --pipeline_config_path = training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

I expected training to start and showing losses and accuracy at each step but the command isn't running.

Comment: Hi! Have you solved your problem? I'm facing the same with another model

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the command in the wrong format.

```
python3 research/object_detection/legacy/train.py \
--logtostderr --train_dir=training/ \
--pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

There should be no space in between `--train_dir` and `=` and `training`. Otherwise the `=` is interpreted as the argument's value. Also it is recommended to use `model_main.py`, so the correct way to call is:

```
python3 object_detection/model_main.py --alsologtostderr \
--model_dir=training/\
--pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll write a bit more detail for those who may have encountered the above error.

The above error is due to incorrect writing the command as the person above said.

`--train_dir=training/`

The above needs to be corrected. White space should be removed based on '='.

If the above error occurs even after removing the space, you need to check again whether to put the filename or folder path as an argument.